# i64vec2 copy constructor suddenly starts corrupting stuff

Tags: c++, glm-math

Okay, I'm sorry. It seems that Visual Studio just goes crazy and the values are REALLY fine. As to why this happens and when, I have no idea.

There is a complete sample at the end, I'd like to know if it does this crazy thing for you as well. Try it with x86 and x64 builds and look at what the debugger says the value is.

Maybe this is a good thing though, now I won't miss needless copying.

---

I find this really odd. Whenever I copy a glm::i64vec2 it gets corrupted.

But if i do just this line:

```
glm::i64vec2 copy(glm::i64vec2(1, 1));
```

In my main, it just works.
I have deleted all object files and rebuilt the program from scratch.. any ideas what might be wrong?

The only one I can think of is that I have included headers in different order in different places and that somehow messed this up.

What I really should use here is const reference, but still this scares the crap out of me. One of these could easily stay hidden as a bug and cause lots of headache for me.

[image: Fine]

[image: !Fine]

---

I just found another bug this caused. This time it happens inside a single class.

This fails, but the same works in main

```
bool test(glm::i64vec2 p_worldPos)
{
  return p_worldPos.x == 1;
}

void QuadTree::getObjectsHitInPriority(glm::i64vec2 const & p_worldPos, std::vector<Object*> & p_objects)
{
  test(p_worldPos);
```

---

Um, I don't know what this means, but the following observation has been made. In my program main.cpp this fails

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct whatthehell
{
    bool test(glm::u64vec2 p_test)
    {
        return p_test.x == 1;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    whatthehell hell;

    if (hell.test(glm::u64vec2(1, 1)) == false)
    {
        std::cout << "What the hell\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ok, update. This works with x86 but not on x64 with my VS2015. Can anyone test this?

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but are you compiling in release mode?

Comment: Nope, debug mode and x64.

Comment: Hmm, this looks like stack corruption to me. You're sure that this is the actual value and not just invalid display in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, the value is correct. I was looking into this because the function did not do as i expected it to.

Comment: I can test this when I get home, I'm using GLM in my homebrew engine project as well; I think our projects are pretty similar, actually. As an aside, were you the same guy asking about SDL events a couple weeks ago? I had an answer all written out but then the question got closed for literally no reason. So stupid.

Comment: Yeah, that's me. I thought it was a valid question too, maybe people didn't understand any of it. I got it working though, what i didn't realize was that SDL_Event was keeping track of the events, and it shouldn't be destroyed.